# Update user attributes without changing password in rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rails-admin

In my app, I use devise to generate User model, add some attributes like job, role,... to this.
In rails_admin page, when edit an user, I only show fields: email, job, role, idcard (no include password and password_confirmation fields)
When I click Save, it show error because the password is shorter than 6 characters.
In the console, if I try

```
User.last.update_attributes(:role => "admin", "idcard" => "1233131")
```

It'll get the same error!
How can I fix this? Because the rails_admin (I think and be sure) didn't use update in registrations_controller to update user!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh, yeah! I just fix my own problem  by delete two validate of user model

```
validates :password, :length => { :minimum => 6 }
validates :password, :confirmation => true
```

and when I type

```
User.first.update_attributes(:email => "abc@yahoo.com")
```

It worked!!!